# How to clone or copy running windows 7 to child partition

Tags: windows-7, command-line, partitioning, clone

Is there anyway to clone partition to partition in windows 7  for free using some kind of command line tool so that i can set block size to increase speed

i google and found some tools like dd for windows and dcfldd 
but when i use them it gives me error like access denied and permission denied
i tried to login as administrator 
using: net user administrator on
but its same problem

dcfldd bs=4096 if=.\k: of=\.\m:

while its working to create image file :

dcfldd bs=4096 if=.\k: of=\.\M:\filename.ext

some help needed on this
will appreciate
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a third party partition clone/backup software.Unfortunately i dont use any such software but im sure a google search will turn up quite a few.If they support commandline or not is a whole other matter.Obviously you can not copy an OS while youre logged in but i assume you already know that.

Also may i ask why you need commandline tool for this not GUI?